# Java equivalent to Python's itertools.groupby()?

Tags: java, python, functional-programming

Here is an example use case of [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in Python:

```
from itertools import groupby

Positions = [   ('AU', '1M', 1000),
                ('NZ', '1M', 1000),
                ('AU', '2M', 4000),
                ('AU', 'O/N', 4500),  
                ('US', '1M', 2500), 
           ]

FLD_COUNTRY = 0
FLD_CONSIDERATION = 2

Pos = sorted(Positions, key=lambda x: x[FLD_COUNTRY])
for country, pos in groupby(Pos, lambda x: x[FLD_COUNTRY]):
    print country, sum(p[FLD_CONSIDERATION] for p in pos)

# -> AU 9500
# -> NZ 1000
# -> US 2500
```

Is there any language construct or library support in Java that behaves or can achieve what `itertools.groupby()` does above?

Comment: You don't exactly explain what groupby does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest thing might be in [Apache Functor](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/functor/). Have a look at [Examples of Functors, Transformers, Predicates, and Closures in Java](http://apachecommonstipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2009/01/examples-of-functors-transformers.html) where you will find an example.

BTW - don't expect to see something like in Python, where these things are implemented in 2-3 lines of code. Java has not been designed as language with good functional features. It simply doesn't contain lots of syntactic sugar like scripting languages do. [Maybe in Java 8 will see more of these things coming together](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/). That is the reason why Scala came up,   [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662091/are-there-any-more-elegant-ways-of-handling-lists-in-java-python-vs-java) that I made sometime ago where I got really good related answers. As you can see in my question implementing a recursive function is much nicer in Python than in Java. Java has lots of good features but definitely functional-programing is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same question and found neoitertools: http://code.google.com/p/neoitertools/ via the answers to this question: [Is there an equivalent of Python's itertools for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528966/is-there-an-equivalent-of-pythons-itertools-for-java)

Comment: Dear CDMP, could you please outline how a solution might look like? Links tend to date out ...